# Use of compiler flag "-static-libgcc"

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, solaris, cc

what is the exact use of -static-libgcc compiler flag in gcc ?

In particular, why are they used in Solaris machines ?

Answer (score 0):

The shared version is required on Solaris to properly support exception handling across shared libraries.

http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/~mk/prog0001/files/shared.txt